# How to use DI with Unity after registering DLLs dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I register my Dlls dynamically with Unity

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    string dependenciesPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SpecificDll");
    string[] dependencies = Directory.GetFiles(dependenciesPath);
    Dictionary<Type, Type> pluginMappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    //Load Dependency Assemblies
    foreach (string fileName in dependencies)
    {
        //Get type interface and plugin type
        ....
    }
    foreach (var mapping in pluginMappings)
    {
        container.RegisterType(mapping.Key, mapping.Value);
    }
}
```

I used to register my class like this way

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

And use it like that

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private Service _service;
    public MyController(Service service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to do when I load the assemblies dynamically.

Can you help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created a third project with common interfaces.

In my Dll :

```
    public class ServiceSpe : IServiceSpe
    {
        public string GetLabel()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

In my common project :

```
    public interface IServiceSpe
    {
        string GetLabel();
    }
```

In my controller :

```
    public MyController()
    {
    }

    public MyController(IServiceSpe serviceSpe)
    {
        if (serviceSpe != null)
        {
            string result = serviceSpe.GetLabel();
        }
    }
```

If dependency contains class with interface "IServiceSpe" :

MyController(IServiceSpe serviceSpe) is called

else

MyController() is called